# angular unit test using localstorage

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I using localstorage for retrieve data and display in form, when i run the test i need to set this data previous to call to `expect`.

```js
it('testing data from localstorage', () => {
        localStorage.setItem('data', '{}');
        expect(component.isData).toBe(false);
    });
```

the first not work, but key in localstorage exist, i need to refresh chrome browser for pass the test.

How add a time for wait to localstorage and then run expect ?

Comment: The reason why you won't get new data from localStorage highly depends on how the rest of your test is set up and where you call localStorage.getItem('data'). setItem call won't automatically be reflected to your local isData variable. If you have your getItem call in ngOnInit then you want to call setItem before you call fixture.detectChanges() and call expect after this. All this assumes your component doesn't have any async logic tied to this.

Comment: I would recommend wrapping localStorage with an injected service, then your component can easily be tested against a test double of the service (and you're not coupling to an interface you don't own, you can leverage observables, ...).